# Android SDK | sdkmanager --list giving unreadable output on Windows 10

Tags: android, list, cmd, sdk, output

I have an issue. As you know android sdk gui is removed. I am trying to using via sdkmanager. when i type on windows cmd "sdkmanager --list" 
the output : [unreadable parts with 
[image]
btw : I try

```
sdkmanager --list > list.txt
```

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Please inline the output (don't use an image) and format code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this with --verbose option.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html

Answer (score 0):

You can list the items with grep key. This is going to be good reference using command line tools: http://eqdn.tech/android-development-on-the-command-line/

```
sdkmanager.bat --list | grep -i 'platforms;.*'
```

sdkmanager.bat will retrieve all items and you can filter this list with grep and value what you looking for.

[image: using grep]